# how to print province name using provinceid in laravel using eager?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am developing app using `laravel 5.6`.

In my application I have three tables as provinces, districts, towns and these models have following relationship:

```
Province
    public function districts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(District::class);
    }

District
    public function province()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Province::class);
    }

Town
    public function district()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(District::class);
    }
```

Now I have data grab using eager loder in `Controller`:

```
$town_list = Town::with('district.province')->groupBy('provinceid')->get();
```

and dropdown selection input in `blade` file,

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Province</label>
        <select name="province_id" id="province_id" class="form-control input dynamic" data-dependent="district_id" >
            <option value="">Select Province</option>
            @foreach($town_list as $town)
            <option value="{{$town->provinceid}}">{{$town->provinceid}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        </div>
```

now I can see provinceid in My selection input but I need print province name in my selection input, my table structure,

```
provinces
id    name
1    alabama
2    prodova

districts
id   name    province_id
1     x          1
2     y          2

towns
id   name    district_id    province_id
1     gh          1              1
2     ju          2              2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can remove that `province_id` from your `Town` table. District of the town gives you required province id (`$town->district->province_id` or `$town->district->province->id`).

Also, to print Province name, you can chain your relationships. As mentioned, you can get it using `$town->district->province->name`.

```
<option value="{{$town->district->province->id}}">{{$town->district->province->name}}</option>
```

Comment: occurred this error msg **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: `->groupBy('provinceid')`
is this a valid one? there doesn't seem to be any column with name `provinceid`. Also, can you message me full error? It might be more helpful to detect issue.

Comment: full error msg is **Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\banda\Desktop\dgtr\resources\views\cars\carform.blade.php) in 218536a4e8b355ff34185defd1fcb8465089362a.php line 26**

Comment: my line 26 is **<option value="{{$town->provinceid}}">{{$town->district->province['provincename']}}</option>**

Comment: `<option value="{{$town->district->province->id}}">{{$town->district->province->name}}</option>` or `<option value="{{$town->province_id}}">{{$town->district->province->name}}</option>`.

Comment: As you have mentioned, your `Town` has `district` and `District` has `province`. With such relationships defined in respective models, you can access your province from town using lazy loading chaining relationships as `$town->district->province` and as it has its own id column you can further chain `->id` to get the province id or `->name` to get province name. If that doesn't work, there might be some issue in relationship declaration or database column names. Please verify everything once again.
If you failed again, let you contact me [@twitter](https://twitter.com/raazpuspa)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177744/discussion-between-pusparaj-and-banda).